# How unsafe is it to run my PC without fans attached to the CPU heatsink

Tags: cpu, fan, overheating, heatsink, cpu-cooler

I have booted the PC for just a minute but I'd like to know if it would be safe to run some games without fans directly attached to the heatsink. Unfortunately the fans are currently broken and need to be repaired/replaced. There there two front case fans and one rear (shown in the image).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't do that..

Comment: So you've got a high-end system and it will take a few days to repair, and you want to risk it to play some games?  That's a serious Jones you've got there.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Its not a great idea as it will put unnecessary stress on your computer - and assuing by "a game" you are talking about something which warrants a decent GPU and serious cooling as implied by 2 case fan's, you won't be able to do much gaming on it.

That said, IN THEORY you will not do too much damage - all non-ancient Intel CPUs have protection to prevent them from overheating - so as your system starts heating up it will slow the CPU down to reduce the heat generated - probably making your game jerky / unplayable anyway.

That said, depending on your case design and heatsink, if you have a closed case you may - if you are lucky - find that the airflow forced through the case and over the CPU fan might make things more-or-less useable - but it's still going to put more stress on the CPU then it's likely designed for.